# How do you keep Materia when using Chapter Select? What carriers over when swapping chapters?

Tags: final-fantasy-7-remake

I've read conflicting sites about how and when Materia is kept while using Chapter Select.

**A real life example:**

I'm on chapter chapter 6 on a hard play through and leveled up several green Materia. I completed chapter 6 and started chapter 7 then swapped to chapter 14 so I could unlock  Battle Intel Report 18 and get MP Absorb.

I obtained the MP Absorb materia and used chapter select to swap back to chapter 7, but MP Absorb wasn't available.

**Question**

When is Materia (and items, exp, levels, etc) actually "kept"? I assume its only officially registered as "kept" when you complete a chapter. Is that correct? Does the same apply to exp, levels, and items?

*Disclaimer: I don't play a lot of "modern" games with new game plus, etc, so I might not be down with the typical flow*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your characters' equipment and XP are "saved" at the end of each chapter. So if you want to get the MP Absorb from chapter 14 and take it back to chapter 7 with you, you have to make sure to finish chapter 14 with it. Just grabbing it and quitting back out to Chapter Select immediately isn't enough. Unfortunately my experience has been that it isn't entirely clear exactly when a chapter transition occurs; keep an eye on the main quest, which should tell you.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @Paul Z